# Ifelse in function returning NaN for negative numbers

Tags: r

I dont understand why this function returns NaN for negative values of x.

```
lambda <- 2.77 
alpha <- 0.88 

# function 

util <- function( x, a, l){
  
  ifelse(x >=0, x^a, l * (x^a) )
  
}
```

for x I insert a number from a data frame. If the number is positive, I get the correct result. If it is negative though, it returns NaN

```
> util(-0.5,alpha,lambda)
[1] NaN
```

Can someone explain why or suggest a solution?

Comment: Roots of negative numbers are complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
util <- function(x, a, l) {
  ifelse(x >= 0, x^a, l * (as.complex(x)^a))
}
```

and you will see

```
> util(-0.5, alpha, lambda)
[1] -1.399432+0.554074i
```